# React update children from higher level parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as you can see LoginContainer.js contains a component Form and inside form there are multiple children.
in Form.js i loop over the children add some custom method to the children props and finally output them.

the isFetching comes from the redux store.

in LoginContainer when `isFetching` is changed to true the FormButton component doesn't recieve the new prop value because its owned by the Form component.

i know why this is happening because the Form component is not changed directly and wont update so the children wont be rerendered.

is there a way that Form.js will update its children?

LoginContainer.js

```
 @connect((store) => ({
      isFetching: store.users.isFetching,
      error: store.users.error
    }), (dispatch) => ({
      action: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    }))
    class LoginContainer extends Component {

      handleAuth(user) {
       this.props.action.fetchAndHandleUser(user.email, user.password)
      }

            render() {

                const { isFetching } = this.props

                return (
                    <h1>Login to VMS</h1>
                    <Form onFormSubmit={this.handleAuth} formClass={styles.loginForm}>

                      ....

                      <FormButton
                        type="submit"
                        buttonText="Login"
                        showLoader={isFetching} // default value is false
                        loaderText="Authenticating" />

                    </Form>
                )
            }
        }
```

Form.js

```
    class Form extends Component {

      ....

      componentWillMount() {

        this.children = {}
        this.inputs   = {}
        this.model    = {}

        this.registerInputs(this.props.children)
      }

      registerInputs(children) {

        this.children = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {

          if(child.props.name) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
              bindToForm: this.bindToForm,
              unbindFromForm: this.unbindFromForm,
              validate: this.validate
            })
          }

          if(child.props.children) {
            this.registerInputs(child.props.children)
          }
          else {
            return child
          }
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={this.props.formClass}>
            {this.children}
          </form>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: isFetching in the LoginContainer.js is a props?

Comment: it comes from the redux store, its a destructed prop

Comment: Can you post that code?

Comment: i edited my post, when i console.log isFetching i changes from false to true. so i know that is working. but the children doesn't rerender or recieve new props

Comment: where did you call registerInputs?

Comment: i call it above the .... otherwise its alot of code in the post. i will edit my post where i call this.registerInputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149240/discussion-between-julez-and-henrique-oecksler-bertoldi).

Answer (score 0):

Bind the value of isFetching in state. Then update the state when the value change to make react re-render.

Comment: already try'd that. the problem is that the children not rerender